# React children is not required in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this component:

```
interface TestI = {
  id: string;
}
const Test = ({children, id}: React.PropsWithChildren<TestI>) => {
  return <div id={id}>{children}</div>
}
```

Usage of the component:

```
<Test id={'hi'}></Test>
```

I expect to get a warning from TS that i did not use `children` for `Test` component. 
 **Question**: How to make children required?

Comment: Change your return to  `<div id={id}>{children}</div>`  Is your IDE not complaining about that?

Comment: @possum, it was a typo in my example, thanks. But it does not change the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make children required?

Since there's no any built-in type that has `children` as *required* prop (`FC` and `PropsWithChildren` has `children` as *optional*), you will have to add it by yourself.

```
interface TestI {
  id: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Test = ({ children, id }: TestI) => {
  return <div id={id}>{children}</div>
}

<Test id="test"></Test> // Property 'children' is missing error
```

Comment: could you please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74474194/using-typescript-generics-in-reactjs-function-components

Answer (score 2):

You should declare that your component requires `children` explicitly:

```
const TestComponent = (props: {children: React.ReactNode, id: string}) => {
    return (
        <div id={props.id}>{props.children}</div>
    );
}
```

See [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4AVJBgYV0hqRvgF44AFGBxg6ALjgBvNAAtgAGwAmRGhOToYAOnUYAchEVIANHGCKJDKMBoBzAL4BKOLwB8U8nE9wiMAK5QaQQ8vEIAeRWAAN1NFXklhCFFNMzsXeJE6TVkFZW47UIB6CMiXYM8HCjtKTF8aDGBaOABBMDABJ0ky7yQ-ALhQ5jYOWm54M14AIhgWGAmXQsGYdnARnhdKoA) in TS playground.

Also, `children` are optional in `React.PropsWithChildren` type - that's why there is no error ([link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L799) to types).
And I wouldn't use this generic anyway, since it only adds `children` prop to the passed type and usage of such generics is [discouraged](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177) by community.